# Create hash from array of names and variables (can't convert Array into String)

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to build a nested array of hashes. I have an array, `branch`, that looks like this:

```
branch = ["handbags", "womens-shoes", "womens-beauty", "womens-clothes"]
```

Then I have another array that contains things that go with `handbags`:

```
handbags = ["wallets", "backpacks", "clutches", "evening-handbags", "hobo-bags", "satchels", "shoulder-bags", "tote-bags"]
```

I want to insert, in a loop, the `handbags` array into the `branch` array, so that I get something like this:

```
branch = {"handbags" => ["wallets", "backpacks", "clutches", "evening-handbags", "hobo-bags", "satchels", "shoulder-bags", "tote-bags"], "womens-shoes"],...}
```

I attempt it this like this:

```
def insert_branch(branch, branch_index, candidate, candidate_index)
    branch[[branch_index], branch[branch_index]] ||= {}
    branch[[branch_index], branch[branch_index]] = candidate[candidate_index]  
end
```

where

```
candidate[candidate_index] = ["wallets", "backpacks", "clutches", "evening-handbags", "hobo-bags", "satchels", "shoulder-bags", "tote-bags"]
```

gives me

> can't convert Array into Integer

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you giving us all of that code? You never use `branch`, `handbags`, or `insert_branch`. Also you never define `candidate`.

Comment: I don't think an [ array ] can become an { associative array } like that. But I don't actually know Ruby, so you shouldn't listen to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ruby [Array class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) says:

> Arrays are ordered, integer-indexed collections of any object.

so the problem is that your index must be an integer, but you're trying to assign to the array using a string index. You might consider converting the whole thing to a hash (so that you can use strings as keys) or you can place a hash or sub-array into the array at the proper index like so:

```
idx = branch.index "handbags"
branch[idx] = { "handbags" => handbags }
```

You should also take a look at Array#zip, and see if that will provide you the functionality you need.

Comment: thanks for the straightforward answer! This worked for me nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can't index an array with an object different then an integer. You have to use a hash.
As branch is an array, Ruby expects a Integer to index each element and as you're giving it another array, it tries to convert it into an Integer, hence producing the error.
Try this:

```
branch = Hash.new #unnecessary, but makes the class explicit
handbags = ["wallets", "backpacks", "clutches", "evening-handbags", "hobo-bags", "satchels", "shoulder-bags", "tote-bags"]
branch["handbags"] = handbags
```

branch.inspect will produce:

```
"{\"handbags\"=>[\"wallets\", \"backpacks\", \"clutches\", \"evening-handbags\", \"hobo-bags\", \"satchels\", \"shoulder-bags\", \"tote-bags\"]}"
```

Comment: +1 for being write about why what the OP was doing was wrong, and explaining it. However, this answer is missing what I _think_ was the OP's intention of looping over an array of names and finding local variables with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have:

```
array = ["foo", "bar"]
foo   = ...
bar   = ...
```

then you are out of luck: you cannot (in any good way) get the object referenced by a local variable based on its name. Whenever you find yourself wanting to look a value up by name you should be using a Hash to store the values to retrieve later. i.e. You should change your data structures to instead be something like:

```
array  = ["foo","bar"]
things = {
  "foo" => ...,
  "bar" => ...
}
```

...but of course then you **have** your answer without needing to do any more work.

If for some reason you can't change your code to use a single Hash literal, but if you can change your code instead to use instance variables instead of local variables, you can do this:

```
array  = ["foo", "bar"]
@foo   = ...
@bar   = ...
branch = Hash[ array.map{ |name| [name,instance_variable_get("@#{name}")] } ]
```

*The above code requires Ruby 1.9; if you are instead using old 1.8 then say so.*

Seen in action:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = %w[foo bar jim]
#=> ["foo", "bar", "jim"]

irb(main):002:0> @foo = %w[ 1 2 3 ]
#=> ["1", "2", "3"]
irb(main):003:0> @bar = %w[ 4 5 6 ]
#=> ["4", "5", "6"]
irb(main):004:0> @jim = %w[ 7 8 9 ]
#=> ["7", "8", "9"]

irb(main):006:0> Hash[ a.map{ |name| [name,instance_variable_get("@#{name}")] } ]
#=> {"foo"=>["1", "2", "3"], "bar"=>["4", "5", "6"], "jim"=>["7", "8", "9"]}
```

Comment: thanks for your thorough reply. This was kind of a tough call, but I gave this one to CodeGnome, just because it was a little simpler for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have indexing problems going on in your code.  The statement:

```
branch[[branch_index], branch[branch_index]]
```

is being understood by Ruby as trying to access `branch` at index `[branch_index]` (which isn't a valid index... it's an array) and look at `branch[branch_index]` many elements (which also isn't a valid number of elements... it's a string).

I think that what you actually want here is:

```
def insert_branch(branch, branch_index, candidate, candidate_index)
    branch[branch_index] = {branch[branch_index] => candidate[candidate_index]}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a little off. Maybe this will give you some guidance.

```
branch = ["handbags", "womens-shoes", "womens-beauty", "womens-clothes"]

handbags = ["wallets", "backpacks", "clutches", "evening-handbags", "hobo-bags", "satchels", "shoulder-bags", "tote-bags"]

def insert_branch(catagories,catagories_index,branch)
  catagories[catagories_index] = Hash[catagories[catagories_index],branch] 
end

insert_branch(branch,0,handbags)


>> p branch  # OUTPUT IS
>> [{"handbags"=>["wallets", "backpacks", "clutches", "evening-handbags", "hobo-bags", "satchels", "shoulder-bags", "tote-bags"]}, "womens-shoes", "womens-beauty", "womens-clothes"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response slindsey3000! You're approach seems pretty valid to me - gave this one to CodeGnome because it seemed more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do can be done just with:

```
a = %w|Things Animals Cities|
things = %w|Desk Table Lamp|

a[0] = {a[0] => things}

a
=> [{"Things"=>["Desk", "Table", "Lamp"]}, "Animals", "Cities"]
```

In your case, it's

```
branch[0] = {branch[0] => handbags}
```

**Edit:** using metaprogramming, you could look up for arrays based on their name:

```
categories = %w|Things Animals Cities|
things = %w|Desk Table Lamp|
animals = %w|Dog Cat Turtle|
cities = %w|London Rome Madrid|

result = categories.map do |category| 
  { category => eval(category.downcase) }
end

result
=> [{"Things"=>["Desk", "Table", "Lamp"]},
    {"Animals"=>["Dog", "Cat", "Turtle"]},
    {"Cities"=>["London", "Rome", "Madrid"]}]
```

Note the use of `eval` to get the `Array` named by the category as value.

Comment: I think that the OP is trying to look up the value of the variable based on the string in the array.

Comment: Thanks albomoriconi! I appreciate your response. Gave this one to CodeGnome, but I think you've got the gist of it too.